# Is PDFDocument in ios a .pdf file?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uikit

I am able to create a PDFDocument from an image in ios and view it using PDFView.  I would like to save this document.  If I write this PDFDocument to a file system, is it a .pdf?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: PDFDocument: An object that represents PDF data or a PDF file and defines methods for writing, searching, and selecting PDF data. What else would you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem, according to the documentation for [PDFDocument.write(toFile:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436086-write), that there is no suggestion that it writes anything other than a valid PDF file, the parent page for [PDFDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument) suggests that the class mainly exists to read and write to/from valid PDF files.